# Как сделать так, чтобы телеграм-бот предлагал список доступных валют при вводе некоторого значения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Помогите доделать телеграмм бота, чтобы пользователь вводил валюту, а
бот дает курс валюты к рублю, но если он не знает в какой валюте, там
должна быть кнопка (либо там, где сообщение бота, либо ниже), которая выдает
их список. Суть - бот принимает валюту и при этом текстовое исключение, которое он будет обрабатывать, выдавая список всех доступных валют.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def help(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, 
    row_width=3)
    bt1 = types.KeyboardButton("Курсы валют к рублю")
    bt2 = types.KeyboardButton("Моя VK страница")
    markup.add(bt1, bt2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нажмите кнопку с нужной вам функцией", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def get_user_text(message):

    ...
    
    # Что-то типа такого, но без вложенных if блоков (ведь в 
    # ними бот не отвечает на "Показать основные валюты" и 
    # "Показать все валюты" или ошибка, но точно не работает 
    # (не помню))

    elif message.text == "Курсы валют к рублю":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, 
        resize_keyboard=True)
        bt1 = types.KeyboardButton("Показать основные 
        валюты")
        bt2 = types.KeyboardButton("Показать все доступные 
        валюты")
        markup.add(bt1, bt2)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите 
        индекс валюты", reply_markup=markup)

        if message.text == "Показать основные валюты":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """Индекс 
            Название\n
                                                         
            <u>USD  Доллар США</u>\n    
                                                         
            <u>EUR  Евро</u>\n  
                                                         
            <u>GBP  Фунт стерлингов Великобритании</u>\n    
                                                         
            <u>JPY  Японская йена</u>\n 
                                                         
            <u>CHF  Швейцарский франк</u>\n 
                                                         
            <u>CNY  Китайский юань</u>\n
                                                         
            <u>RUB  Российский рубль""",
                             parse_mode="html"
                             )

        elif message.text == "Показать все валюты":
            ...

        else:
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, 
            get_curs_currency)
```

Comment: На [Stack Overflow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Блин я думал тут только на английском языке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вы и написали всякого странного...

```py
from telebot import TeleBot, types

import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)



@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def help_(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    markup.add("Курсы валют к рублю", "Моя VK страница")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нажмите кнопку с нужной вам функцией", reply_markup=markup)
    # стоит  сделать так чтобы срабатывали только эти кнопки
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_curency_and_vk_link)


def get_curency_and_vk_link(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Курсы валют к рублю":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
        markup.add("Показать основные валюты", "Показать все доступные валюты")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите индекс валюты", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, show_general_currency)
    if message.text == "Курсы валют к рублю":
        ...
    else:
        # делаем так чтобы юзер был обязан нажать на кнопки
        # (ну или сам написать то же что на кнопках)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_curency_and_vk_link)


def show_general_currency(message: types.Message):
    list_curency = ['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY', 'CHF', 'CNY', 'RUB']
    # сработает если юзер ввел что-то из списка выше
    if message.text in list_curency:
        ...
    elif message.text == "Показать основные валюты":
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
            text="Индекс Название\n"
                 "<u>USD  Доллар США</u>\n"
                 "<u>EUR  Евро</u>\n"
                 "<u>GBP  Фунт стерлингов Великобритании</u>\n"
                 "<u>JPY  Японская йена</u>\n"
                 "<u>CHF  Швейцарский франк</u>\n"
                 "<u>CNY  Китайский юань</u>\n"
                 "<u>RUB  Российский рубль",
            parse_mode="html")
    elif message.text == "Показать все доступные валюты":
        ...
    else:
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, show_general_currency)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Comment: вложенными блоками if я хотел показать, что мне нужно, но не знал как это сделать.